# Deploy VSTO in Excel Online

Tags: .net, excel, deployment, vsto, office365

I have developed an Excel 2013 Add-in (using Visual Studio 2013) meant to be deployed in Desktop Excel version. It works.
Now, I want to deploy this VSTO to **Excel Online**, I am using Office 365 environment to test the deployment, when I try to upload the Manifest file (XML) file, in this case it a *.vsto file. Upload fails.

Any pointers?
Thanks,
Vikron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSTO add-ins are not supported in Excel Online. Instead consider switching over to the web add-in model. Thanks.

[Office add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins)

Answer (score 1):

COM add-ins (including VSTO based ones) can be loaded by Windows desktop applications (Office applications). You need to develop a web-based add-in instead.  See [Excel JavaScript API programming overview](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-javascript-programming-overview) for more information.